# How can i fix the erro in yii2 wher clause

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 query like

```
$dataProvider = Car::find()
        ->where(['flag'=>1])
        ->orderBy($sort->orders)
        ->all();
```

i need only datas whose flag is 1.But the above query return all datas with flag 0 and 1.How do i get only datas whose flag is one

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataProvider = Car::find()
    ->where(['flag' => 1])
    ->orderBy(['column' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

Please correct the sorting like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataProvider = Car::find()
        ->where(['flag'=>1])
        ->all();
```

If you need with `ORDER BY`:

```
$dataProvider = Car::find()
        ->where(['flag'=>1])
        ->orderBy(['column_to_sort' => SORT_ASC]) //Or DESC, or any other sort orders
        ->all();
```